# Customizing the JSON returned Data in ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, asp.net-web-api

How do I edit and make changes to the JSON returned by ASP.NET Web API before it's returned to client.
For example:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCustomerById(int customerId)
    {
        Customer customer = DAL.GetCustomer(123);

        if (customer == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Could not find                                        customer " + customerId.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customer);
             **//  Here I like to edit the JSON before I return it**
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can create custom serializer and use that instead of standard one

Comment: what exactly are you trying to change? the customer object?

Comment: Yes. Suppose I want to return a date in a specific format- Customer.SomeDate property in special format (UTC)

Comment: How do you create Custom Serializer

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize the JSON to some kind of object, using for example JsonExSerializer library. Then you may begin on modifying the object, serialize it back to JSON and send the modified JSON string. Example using the JsExSer.

```
Serializer ser = new Serializer(typeof(ArrayList));
ArrayList json = ser.Deserialize(jsonstring);
json.Add("something");
string jsonready = ser.Serialize(json);
```

Also note that modifying must be done before returning, being:

```
**//  Here I like to edit the JSON before I return it**
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customer);
```